# PHP documentation function() required $_GET parameters

Tags: php, comments

I've used this syntax to document the functions (an example)

```
/**
* Sum numbers
*
* @param  integer  $FirstNum   First  number to sum
* @param  integer  $SecondNum  Second number to sum
* @throws \Exception           If something's wrong
* @return integer              Sum of first and second number 
*/ 
function sum($FirstNum, $SecondNum){

    if( !is_number($FirstNum) )
        throw new Exception('FirstNum isn\'t a number');

    if( !is_number($SecondNum) )
        throw new Exception('SecondNum isn\'t a number');

    return $FirstNum + $SecondNum
}
```

I have a function that reads the values ​​in the query string and I want to document it. What is the best way?

```
/**
* Sum numbers
*
* ??????????????????????????????????????????????????
* ??????????????????????????????????????????????????
* @throws \Exception           If something's wrong
* @return integer              Sum of first and second number 
*/ 
function sum(){

    $FirstNum  = isset($_GET['FirstNum'])  ? $_GET['FirstNum'] : null;
    $SecondNum = isset($_GET['SecondNum']) ? $_GET['SecondNum'] : null;

    if( !is_number($FirstNum) )
        throw new Exception('FirstNum isn\'t a number');

    if( !is_number($SecondNum) )
        throw new Exception('SecondNum isn\'t a number');

    return $FirstNum + $SecondNum
}
```

I don't know if there's a standard way. I thought of this solution:

```
/**
* @param  integer  $_GET['FirstNum']   First  number to sum
* @param  integer  $_GET['SecondNum']  Second number to sum
```

*Sorry for my google translator's english :(*

Comment: You shouldn't use `@param` tag for `GET` variables because they aren't function parameters. Use `@global` tag.

Comment: @hindmost Have you considered adding that as an answer? It's more an answer than a comment.

Comment: Those query values should be passed as parameters to the function